# How do I Insert unknown amounts of data into a sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have built some presentation software using python3 and flask where users can select photos to purchase and be placed into a cart. The URLs for these photos get placed into a database.

At the moment I have built a database that can input up to six photos but these are explicit and doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

Is there a way that I can add an unknown amount of photos to the database to make it more efficient?  This code does work but I want it to be more efficient and manageable.

```py
 def insert(self, name, img1, img1Size, img2, img2Size, img3, img3Size, img4, img4Size, img5, img5Size, img6, img6Size, price, completed):
        with sql.connect(DATABASE) as con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO orders (name, img1, img1Size, img2, img2Size, img3, img3Size, img4, img4Size, img5, img5Size, img6, img6Size, price, completed) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (name, img1, img1Size, img2, img2Size, img3, img3Size, img4, img4Size, img5, img5Size, img6, img6Size, price, completed))
            con.commit()
            print("Success")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a table which stores your list and a field in that table relates to the order.

Comment: Thanks, I just wondered if there was a better way of doing it. At the moment I have cell's for 6 photos per order so I wanted to know the syntax for not knowing how many photos would be selcted

Comment: I got a downvote so I presume there is a secret better way of doing it.